# How can I run specflow test scenarios in Nunit GUI?

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, specflow, nunit-gui

Hello my question is simple, how can I run specflow test scenarios in Nunit GUI?

The only way I found is:

```
[Test]
[Given(@"Ingreso a la pagina de login del aplicativo")]
    public void GivenIngresoALaPaginaDeLoginDelAplicativo()
    {


        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("url");
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

    }
```

In this way what is executed in the GUI is the definition of the step, **but I need to execute the complete scenario** that contains all the steps (**the feature file**).

I appreciate any support.

Comment: Have you added the `[Binding]` to the class? Make sure you have installed the scenario runner.

Comment: Yes, I have everything right to run the tests from VS, but I need to run the dll from the nunit GUI runner.
`[Binding]
    public class LoginARISteps
    {

        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();


        [Given(@"Ingreso a la pagina de login del aplicativo")]
        public void GivenIngresoALaPaginaDeLoginDelAplicativo()
        {
            
            
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("url");
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

        }`